# Flutter getx json

Tags: json, flutter, helper, flutter-getx

First of all, I apologize to everyone for my low level of English. I want to make an application for a live broadcasting radio station. json link of radio site "http://radyo.comu.edu.tr/json/". This link is refreshed every 5 seconds. and json data is also changing. How can I follow a path from the application?

Answer (score 0):

You can cache the response by using flutter cache manager [Flutter Cache Manager](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cache_manager), store it somewhere and use it. For storage you can use shared preferences,sqlite, hive etc there are a lot of options afterwards

Answer (score 0):

you can use stream builder where data is continually updating
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html

```
StreamBuilder<int>(
 stream: generateNumbers,
 builder: (
    BuildContext context,
    AsyncSnapshot<int> snapshot,
    ) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active
        || snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
         return const Text('Error');
        } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
         return Text(
          snapshot.data.toString(),
          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 40)
          );
        } else {
         return const Text('Empty data');
        }
      } else {
         return Text('State: ${snapshot.connectionState}');
        }
   },
 ),
```